# Firebase Cloud Messaging calling wrong service worker after update

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am successfully able to register tokens for FCM to subscribe to a topic and receive messages using the following code to register the service worker, and get the token is as follows after which it then calls the server to subscribe to the specific topic.

```
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
  const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
  const GET_TOKEN_PARAMS =  { 
    vapidKey: xxxxxx,
    serviceWorkerRegistration: registration
  };
  const current_token = await getToken(messaging, GET_TOKEN_PARAMS);
  return await processNewToken(current_token);
```

This all works fine initially, I'm able to receive messages when the above code runs without a problem.  However, after some time my code stops receiving messages.  This is the problem I am trying to solve.

What I have spotted is that if I stop "service-worker.js" and trigger a message I see that instantly "service-worker.js" starts running.  As such my current working assumption is that when I deploy updates to my code that at some point "service-worker.js" becomes the recipient of messages rather than "firebase-messaging-sw.js".

The code I use to register "service-worker.js" is as follows.

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register('/service-worker.js', {
    registrationOptions: { scope: './' },
    ready (registration) {
      console.log('Service worker is active.')
    },
    registered (registration) {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached (registration) {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound (registration) {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated (registration) {
      console.log('New content is available; close tab then reopen.');
      registration.update();
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

This is using firebase@10.4.0 the service-worker.js is generated using workbox-cli@7.0.0.  Also using register-service-worker@1.7.2

Any help much appreciated as this is currently a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

So I've pivoted from trying to resolve the two service workers to consolidating down to one service worker as so far this seems to work.  I've done this by switching the approach I've used with workbox from generateSW (which created the file "service-worker.js") to having a single service worker and injecting the manifest using injectManifest.  I renamed "firebase-messaging-sw.js" to "service-worker.js" in the public folder, then I added the following at the start of it:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/7.0.0/workbox-sw.js");
workbox.core.skipWaiting();
workbox.core.clientsClaim();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

I had to add the following to workbox-config.js :

```
swSrc: 'public/service-worker.js'
```

Finally instead of calling "workbox generateSW workbox-config.js" I now need to call "workbox injectManifest workbox-config.js"